# Proving $ \lim_{x\to (-1)^-} (2x^2)/((x^2)-1) = \infty $

Tags: calculus, limits

I am studying Infinite Limits and can not understand why this Limit approaches positive infinity instead of negative. I have plotted the graph and see that it indeed does approaches Positive infinity.

This is how I see it:

When the x approaches negative 1 from the left the denominator goes to:

$ ((-1)^2 - 1) = -0 $

The numerator is positive so the division should be 
$ -(\infty) $

Comment: For $x<-1$, $x^2-1>0$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $x$ approaches $-1$ from the left, the value of $x^2$ will be greater than $1$. We have that $x^2>1$ when $|x|>1$. Therefore

$$x^2-1 >0$$

and

$$ \lim_{x\to (-1)^-} \frac{2x^2}{x^2-1} = \frac{2}{0^{+}}=\infty$$

Answer (score 0):

To simplify the determination let $x=-1-y$ with $y\to 0^+$ then

$$\frac{2x^2}{x^2-1}=\frac{2(y+1)^2}{y^2+2y}\to \infty$$